# C# project using Javascript

Tags: c#, reflection

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "javascript";
```

I got this, and don't know what is "0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC" and what is doing all 4 rows.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess from where did you get that GUID? My first guess is that another person wrote that code and you should ask them not us

Comment: What do you mean by “what is doing all 4 rows?

Comment: How should we know which class has that GUID? A guid is just an identifier for a class and the code creates an instance of that class.

Comment: The question's not clear in the least - plz see [ask].

Comment: my mistake sorry..then.. I'm trying to create a calculator in MVS. Is my first project so I search some informations about functions for a calculator and I found this. It seems to make my target easy but I didn't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"` is a [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) - or more exact its string-representation. A guid is basically an identifier for a type. This type is retrieved by `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse(theGuid))` and returns `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl`.

`Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false)` then returns an instance of that type.